# What license does ~/.profile fall under?

Tags: linux, profile, licenses, bash-profile

On Unix & Linux, what license governs usage rights for the '.profile' file? Also what entity can be questioned about compliance?

Comment: I'm not sure any license applies to it.  You write it so apply whatever arbitrary license you want.  `/etc/profile` probably falls under whatever license your OS is distributed under.

Comment: This may be a better question for https://opensource.stackexchange.com/ though

Comment: [Debian’s `.profile`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~doko/+junk/pkg-bash-debian/view/head:/skel.profile) doesn’t have any [licensing information](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~doko/+junk/pkg-bash-debian/view/head:/copyright), which is a bug...

Comment: The `~/.profile` file is usually written and/or customised by each individual user, if it is used at all. Are you specifically referring to the `/etc/skel/.profile` file? On what Unix specifically?

Comment: @Kusalananda, Unix v7 and I was reffering to the '.profile' in every user's folder; the /etc/skel/.profile file doesn't exist in every distro in Linux.